# what's the problem for my atom IDE when i'm trying to run a ncurses project?

Tags: c, atom-editor

Recently i was trying to compile and run a *ncurses* project in Atom IDE.
I successfully link my ncurses to Atom using these commands:

```
pkg-config --libs ncursesw
pkg-config --cflags ncursesw
```

then I copy the results in *Atom > Edit > Config*, But when I try to compile my code I face this error:

```
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
/bin/sh: 2: main.c: not found
```

i tried to change my compiler and I'm using [GCC_MAKE_RUN compiler](http://%20https://atom.io/packages/gcc-make-run) now.

Also I successfully link ncurses to Code::Blocks IDE and compile it easy.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void)
{
initscr();
printw("Hello World !!!");
refresh();
getch();
endwin();
return 0;
}
```

I expected Atom to simply run my code but actually I face errors...

Comment: what do you think about use a real IDE like CLion ?

Comment: You're referring to this? https://ide.atom.io/

Comment: When you say you copied the results to "Atom > Edit > Config" do you mean config.cson? What exactly did you copy? Basically we need more detail about what you did in Atom IDE.

Comment: Which ide package are you using for C language support? ide-cpp?

Comment: i copied the results of "pkg-config --libs ncursesw" and "pkg-config --cflags ncursesw"  which were "-lncursesw -ltinfo" and "-D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/ncursesw" ... i exactly don't know what these results are , but i know these should be copied to Atom to link ncurses to the compiler in "linker setting" and "Other compiler option" through Atom, just like Code::Blocks . wish you can figure out my problem.